# How to send text to Winword in C#?

Tags: c#

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowEx")]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process [] words=Process.GetProcessesByName("winword");
    if(words.Length==0)return;            
    if (words[0] != null)
    {
        IntPtr child= FindWindowEx(words[0].MainWindowHandle, new IntPtr(0), "Edit", null);
        SendMessage(child, 0x000C, 0, textBox1.Text);
    }
}
```

It is not working for Microsoft word..is there any other way?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? Probably the correct solution are the Office PIA that allow you to interact with Office from your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use this method to poke text into Word. It uses custom controls and just won't yield to this approach.  Instead you should use UIAutomation or Office PIA.

Comment: can you please give an example code or any url that has something related to this. Thank you

Comment: Could you give us more detail exactly what you are trying to do. There are a few possible solutions.

Comment: I am trying to append Text and Image into msword.

Comment: Do you need to do this in an existing interactive Word instance, or are you just trying to automate creation/editing of a document.

Comment: Then you can do that with Office PIA as Matteo said.